# Avro schema object generic kafkaTemplate type - produce message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I have situation where my kafka template looks like this:

```
KafkaTemplate<String, InternalSelfServiceData> kafkaTemplate;
```

**Where:** InternalSelfServiceData -> Avro schema object

When i call `kafkaTemplate.send()` my return type is `ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, InternalSelfServiceData>>`. Next i pass this data as a parametr to the next method but i want this method to be generic one so i wanted from them to accept parameter like this `ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, ? extends SpecificRecordBase>>`.

The error that occurs in IntelliJ is:

> Required type:
> ListenableFuture
> <SendResult<String, ? extends SpecificRecordBase>>
>
> Provided: ListenableFuture <SendResult<String,
> InternalSelfServiceData>

Any suggestion what I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your data to bytearray (org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter)

Comment: Are you able to show me example connected with question i asked? I mean use of SpecificDatumWriter with maintaining of kafkaTemplate and ListenableFuture?

Comment: I faced a issue of mismatching provided and required type, while sending data to queue so used the Writer class to encode and send as byte array